# Weird weapons in medieval times

Tags: middle-ages, weapons, historical-research

I know that this will be a bit vague, but here goes: what’s the weirdest weapon ever made/used in the medieval times? I meant in terms of how it’s used. I wrote the man catcher question so I would like to know if there was **any** weapons weirder than that myself.

Comment: Honestly, if you can leave aside that every pre-industrial-themed video game has them so we all grew up seeing them, I think military flails are pretty darn weird.

Comment: Good point @T.E.D.

Comment: What do you mean by weird? The shape of the weapon? The way it was used? I'm afraid that without any criteria, this is just opinion based

Comment: Sorry, I meant the way it was used primarily @Kepotx

Comment: [Aethelflaed's bees](https://hefenfelth.wordpress.com/2011/08/08/lady-aethelflaeds-defense-of-chester-c-907/)

Comment: Rocket cat: https://www.theguardian.com/books/2014/mar/06/fur-flies-rocket-cats-warfare-manual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a weird weapon, but a weird name: the (lengthened) morning star is called in Dutch 'goedendag'. That translates to good morning, or good day.

It is actually a viciously efficient and easy to produce weapon. It was very successfully used during the Battle of the Golden Spurs, in which a Flemish peasant army defeated a large French army of knights.

A morning star was wielded with one hand, with a short handle, a goedendag was more a pole weapon.

- https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goedendag_(wapen)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_Golden_Spurs